# racket function called aunt-names

Tags: function, sorting, racket

I am currently doing a assignment to create a function in racket called aunt-names.  The purpose of the function is to accept a person struct and a list of person structs and return a sorted list of names of all the aunts of that person.  I am not quite sure how to go about starting the function but have already completed these functions that will help with the function:

female-list function

```
(define (female-list flist)   
  (cond [(empty? flist) empty]
        [(equal? 'female (person-sex (first flist)))
         (cons (first flist)
               (female-list (rest flist)))]
        [else (female-list (rest flist))]))
```

sibling? function

```
    (define (sibling? personA personB)
      (cond [(equal? personA personB) false]
            [(equal? (person-father personA) (person-father personB)) true]
            [(equal? (person-mother personA) (person-mother personB)) true]
            [else false]))
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a good start. Before you write the body of aunt-names, here are some ideas for more helper functions that will probably be useful:

- `(female? personA)`: returns true if personA's sex is female
- `(parent-of? personA personB)`: returns true if personA is the father or mother of personB
- `(aunt-or-uncle-of? personA personB)`: returns true if personA is an aunt or uncle of personB
- `(aunt-of? personA personB)`: returns true if personA is an aunt of personB
- `(aunt-or-uncle-list personA people-list)`: returns a list of person structs, where each one is an aunt or uncle of personA (and each one was originally in people-list).
- `(aunt-list personA people-list)`: returns a list of person structs, where each one is an aunt of personA (and each one was originally in people-list). (Note this is different from aunt-names, because it returns whole person-structs instead of just names, and it doesn't sort them.)

These can build on each other, and on the helper functions you already have. This might seem like a lot of tiny functions, but this way each one will be very clear and if something goes wrong you can test them each separately.

Another strategy is to start writing the body of the main function (`aunt-names`) first, and just pretend that any helper function you want to use already exists. For example, while writing `female-names`, you could have broken it down like this:

```
(define (female-list flist)   
  (cond [(empty? flist) empty]
        [(female? (first flist)) ; TODO: go back and write "female?"
         (cons (first flist)
               (female-list (rest flist)))]
        [else (female-list (rest flist))]))
```